# Creating a matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

I´m trying to create a dynamic matrix with an user introduzed number of lines and 6 columns.
I only want to create the matrix so I can get its values when I want to.
I have tried this but the program crashes when it gets here.

```
matriz = (int **)malloc(n_lines * 6 * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < n_lines; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
    {
        current_year = starting_year + i;
        if (current_year % 400 == 0)
        {
            february = 29;
            days = 366;
            hours = 8784;
            minutes = 527040;
            seconds = 31622400;
        }
        else
        {
            february = 28;
            days = 365;
            hours = 8760;
            minutes = 525600;
            seconds = 31536000;
        }
        matriz[i][0] = { current_year };
        matriz[i][1] = { february };
        matriz[i][2] = { days };
        matriz[i][3] = { hours };
        matriz[i][4] = { minutes };
        matriz[i][5] = { seconds };
    }
}
```

Comment: `matriz = (int **)malloc(n_lines * 6 * sizeof(int *))`.. are you sure about `int *`

Comment: I recommend printing the pointers (not what they point to, i.e. e.g. `matriz[i][0]`) each time you assign them, i.e. inside the inner loop, for n_lines > 2. I bet the result will surprise you.

Comment: Yes i understood both cases you mentioned and decided to go with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program crashed because you were accessing chunk of memory as if you have jagged allocated array which is not, resulting in invalid memory access in turn making your program crash.

Well from what I see - you messed up type. Two ways to go about this.

1. ```
   int **matriz;
   matriz = malloc(sizeof *matriz*nlines);
   // error check
   for(size_t i=0; i<nlines; i++){
        matriz[i]= malloc(sizeof *matriz[i] * 6);
        // error check
   }
   ```
2. ```
   int *matriz = malloc(6*nlines*sizeof *matriz);
   // error check 
   matriz[r*6+c] = ... // accessing r-th row c-th column.
   ```

And based on case-1 it will be

```
matriz[i][j] =  current_year ;
```

And in case-2 similarly

```
matriz[i*6+j] = current_year;
```

General code structure would be

```
    if (current_year % 400 == 0)
    {
        ...
        seconds = 31622400;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
        seconds = 31536000;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
    {
        matriz[i][j] = current_year ;
        ...
    }
```

To explain a bit - the first case is allocating a jagged array. First an array of pointers and then each of them are pointing to an array of 6 elements.

Second case is basically allocating a chunk of memory which has `6*nlines` int and `matriz` is pointing to beginning of it. Now that's why you will have to access the elements first calculating the right index for it.

Comment: Thank you so much @coderredoc , i apreciated your explanation as well